# STACKOVERFLOW EMERGENCY ! REACT-ROUTER-DOM installation failing

Tags: reactjs, npm

I installed react-router-dom from my root directory using npm, but when I run my application, I get the following error:

/src/App.jsx
Cannot find file: 'react-router-dom.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: 'C:\Users\george\ompex\node_modules\react-router-dom\esm\Desktop'.

Comment: react-router-dom    remove .js

Comment: exactly! i dont have .js in my import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

Answer (score 0):

Did you install with React not express server? and Try the following in React Root `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: i tried npm cache clean --force, then npm install react-router-dom and it did not work

Comment: try `npm uninstall react-router-dom` then `npm cache clean --force` then `npm i react-router-dom`